# How to read SESSION_ID in HttpWebResponse.Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies

I got Response Header like this

```
    Date: Wed, 17 Sep 2014 06:13:37 GMT  
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked  
    Connection: keep-alive  
    Set-Cookie: SESSION_ID=8ffc5f91d4d31130267b3a304acd235d; path=/; secure; HttpOnly  
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8ffc5f91d4d31130267b3a304acd235d; path=/; secure; HttpOnly  
    Set-Cookie: SESSION_KEY=; path=/; secure   
    Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT   
    Pragma: no-cache   
    Cache-control: no-cache  
    P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP COR NID CURa OUR NOR STA"  
    Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I would like get `SESSION_ID` from the Set-Cookie.
This is my sample code :

```
pl_wResData = (HttpWebResponse)pl_wReqData.GetResponse();

pl_strResList = pl_wResData.Headers["Set-Cookie"].Replace(',', ';').Split(';');

for (int i = 0; i < pl_strResList.Length; i++)
{
    pl_strValueList = pl_strResList[i].Split('=');

    if (pl_strValueList[0].Equals("SESSION_ID"))
    {
        strSID = pl_strValueList[1].ToString();
        break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows simple way to get `SESSION_ID` in `Set-Cookie`.
Please help me!!

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Cookies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies.aspx) property of [`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx).

([`WebRequest.GetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) returns a [`WebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx), but if the underlying request is HTTP, the runtime type is `HttpWebResponse` and you can cast the result.)

The `Cookies` object is a collection of [`Cookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.aspx) objects indexed by name or numerically.

So something like

```
((HttpWebResponse)myResponse).Cookies["SESSION_ID"].Value
```

should do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately, I've already try this and it didn't work....... when I tried like this I got 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' this exception error message....

Comment: @HojinKim In that case: which object was not set? Have you looked at the `Cookies` collection in a debugger? (Mostly likely you're not getting the cookies you think you are.)

Comment: Hmmm.... I checked Cookie, in this case any Cookie is not set in this response header. I just request to third party website and get this response header. So it's too complicated to get SESSION_ID in this Header....

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem....
Just Create CookieCentainer befor responding request data.... 
the sample code like this

```
pl_wReqData.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
pl_wResData = (HttpWebRespons)pl_wReqData.GetResponse();

if(pl_wResData.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
{
    strSID = pl_wResData.Cookies["SESSION_ID"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `cookie collection`, something like this:

```
foreach (Cookie cookie in pl_wResData.Cookies)
{
   if (cookie.Name != "SESSION_ID")
      continue;
   strSID = cookie.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I've already try this and it does work. SESSION_ID is value of the Set-Cookie so I can get it using cookiecollection.....